# Min android api for firestore?

Tags: android, api, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've just tried using my app on an android device with api lvl 16 but whenever a firestore function is getting called it's crashing saying that the device is offline.(Which is not the case) On Api 19+ it works perfectly fine. So I was wondering if there is a min api.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for Firebase SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) states that Android 4.0 (API level 14) is the minimum.  If there is something that's not behaving the way you expect, [file a bug report](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features).

Comment: Alright thank you, but I thought about setting min api of my app to 19 anyways so I'll propably leave it as it is. I was just wondering.